# MSBuild and Xmlmassupdate having trouble changing xml

Tags: msbuild, xmlmassupdate

Using XmlMassupdate how to change:

Change this:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <StackOverflow.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="StackOverflow_References_References" serializeAs="String">
        <value>OLDVALUE</value>
      </setting>
    </StackOverflow.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

To this:

```
  <applicationSettings>
    <StackOverflow.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="StackOverflow_References_References" serializeAs="String">
        <value>NEWVALUE</value>
      </setting>
    </StackOverflow.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update to a newer version of xmlmassupdate to get this to work.